# Amount in text Odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73kBu.png)I want to convert the total amount showing in account invoice to word, please help. I could not solve it. Also I already tried to it but no luck

Comment: Please share the exact code you already have tried. This makes it possible for stackoverflowers to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Did you want it in your report or for your record ?

> For Report

In Odoo10 I usually do like this:

```
<t t-esc="o.amount_total" t-esc-options='{"widget": "num2words","case":"capital"}'/>
```

Here we have to install num2words module for its correct working. You can install it by

`pip install num2words` or just google.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following method for your problem.

```
def Numbers_To_Words (number):
    dictionary = {'1': "one", '2': "two", '3': "three", '4': "four", '5': "five", '6': "six",
            '7': "seven", '8': "eight", '9': "nine", '0': "zero"}
    return " ".join(map(lambda x: dictionary[x], str(number)))

print Numbers_To_Words(1234)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is num2words module in python install `pip install num2words` [num2words](https://pypi.org/project/num2words/)

```
from num2words import num2words

@api.multi
def numtoword_s(self, amount_total):
    return (num2words(amount_total, lang='en_IN')).title()+" only"
```

create this function in invoice file and call the application from qweb pass the amount you want to convert into text format.

Comment: I want to show the amount in word in the web server not on the report.

Comment: I added a screenshot on the question, so i want the amount_to_text to show after total amount, also i tried to install num2words but it return an errorImportError: No module named num2words

Comment: So just add a compute. Did you try pip install num2words?

Comment: add code, what you're tried to achieve that functionality.

Comment: yes, I have tried pip install num2words but it giving me an error. so here's my code:       
                                                                                                    
   class InvoiceTemplate(models.Model):
    _inherit = ['account.invoice']                                                                                                    

    text_amount=fields.Char(string='Total')

 @api.multi
def numtoword_s(self, amount_total):
    return (num2words(amount_total, lang='en_IN')).title()+" only"

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you out : https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/code/216839/number-to-word-converter-python

Also this one too :https://pypi.org/project/inflect/
This is a py lib which represent your number into relevant words