# How can i get Amount in word in odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

How can i get amount in words in invoice in odoo-10. I have added following code in account_invoice.py

```
    @api.multi    
def amount_to_text(self, amount, currency):
    convert_amount_in_words = amount_to_text_en.amount_to_text(amount, lang='en', currency='')        
    convert_amount_in_words = convert_amount_in_words.replace(' and Zero Cent', ' Only ')         
    return convert_amount_in_words
```

xml

```
    t-esc="o.amount_to_text(o.amount_total, o.currency_id)" />
```

I got the following error

How can i get amount in words in invoice in odoo-10. I have added following code in account_invoice.py

```
    @api.multi    
def amount_to_text(self, amount, currency):
    convert_amount_in_words = amount_to_text_en.amount_to_text(amount, lang='en', currency='')        
    convert_amount_in_words = convert_amount_in_words.replace(' and Zero Cent', ' Only ')         
    return convert_amount_in_words
```

xml

```
    t-esc="o.amount_to_text(o.amount_total, o.currency_id)" />
```

I got the following error

```
     Odoo Server Error
     Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/bahmni-erp/addons/report/controllers/main.py", line 96, in report_download
response = self.report_routes(reportname, docids=docids, converter='pdf')
       File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 507, in response_wrap
        response = f(*args, **kw)
      File "/opt/bahmni-erp/addons/report/controllers/main.py", line 45, in report_routes
         pdf = report_obj.with_context(context).get_pdf(docids, reportname, data=data)
        File "/opt/bahmni-erp/addons/report/models/report.py", line 181, in get_pdf
         html = self.with_context(context).get_html(docids, report_name, data=data)
          File "/opt/bahmni-erp/addons/report/models/report.py", line 147, in get_html
return self.render(report.report_name, docargs)
          File "/opt/bahmni-erp/addons/report/models/report.py", line 123, in render
return view_obj.render_template(template, values)
         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0-py2.7.egg/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 1052, in render_template
return self.browse(self.get_view_id(template)).render(values, engine)
        File "/opt/bahmni-erp/addons/web_editor/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 26, in render
return super(IrUiView, self).render(values=values, engine=engine)
       File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0-py2.7.egg/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 1072, in render
return self.env[engine].render(self.id, qcontext)
       File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0-py2.7.egg/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb/ir_qweb.py", line 53, in render
return super(IrQWeb, self).render(id_or_xml_id, values=values, **context)
        File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0-py2.7.egg/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb/qweb.py", line 251, in render
self.compile(template, options)(self, body.append, values or {})
       File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0-py2.7.egg/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb/qweb.py", line 320, in _compiled_fn
raise e
    QWebException: 'account.invoice' object has no attribute 'amount_to_text'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0-py2.7.egg/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb/qweb.py", line 318, in _compiled_fn 
    return compiled(self, append, values, options, log)
       File "<template>", line 1, in template_account_account_invoice_report_duplicate_440
      File "<template>", line 3, in body_call_content_439
     AttributeError: 'account.invoice' object has no attribute 'amount_to_text' 
      Error to render compiling AST  
      AttributeError: 'account.invoice' object has no attribute 'amount_to_text'
       Template: account.account_invoice_report_duplicate  
      Path: /templates/t/t/div/div[4]/div/table/tr[3]/td[2]/span[2]  
      Node: <span t-esc="o.amount_to_text(o.amount_total, o.currency_id)"/>
```

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53029729/amount-in-text-odoo-10 but there aren't any upvoted or accepted answers, which unfortunately is normal on Odoo questions...

Answer (score 1):

In Odoo 11 I usually do like this :

```
<t  t-esc="doc.currency_id.amount_to_text(doc.amount_total)"/>
```

Here `currency_id` field should be there in your record.`amount_total` here is total amount's field in quotation.
Try this in Odoo 10 but I'm not sure it will work in Odoo 10.

In Odoo10 I usually do like this:

```
<t t-esc="o.amount_total" t-esc-options='{"widget": "num2words","case":"capital"}'/>
```

Here we have to install `num2words` module for its correct working.
You can install it by `pip install num2words` or just google.